# Confusion regarding the proof for De Morgan's law

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

From Wikipedia's formal proof of De Morgan's law $ (A \cap B )'= A' \cup B' $.
Given proof:

\begin{align} x  \in (A \cap B )'
\end{align}
\begin{align} \implies x  \notin (A \cap B )
\end{align}
\begin{align} \implies x  \notin A  \lor x \notin B
\end{align}
And proof goes on. **But my question is that isn't the following proof also correct?**
\begin{align} x  \in (A \cap B )'
\end{align}
\begin{align} \implies x  \notin (A \cap B )
\end{align}
\begin{align} \implies x  \in A  \lor x \in B
\end{align}

**If it's correct then what's wrong with the following proof?**
\begin{align} x  \in (A \cap B )'
\end{align}
\begin{align} \implies x  \notin (A \cap B )
\end{align}
\begin{align} \implies x  \in A  \lor x \in B
\end{align}
\begin{align} \implies x  \notin A'  \lor x \notin B'
\end{align}
\begin{align} \implies x  \notin (A' \cap B' )
\end{align}
\begin{align} \implies x  \in (A' \cap B' )'
\end{align}
\begin{align} \therefore    (A \cap B )' \subseteq (A' \cap B' )'
\end{align}

Comment: if $x$ does not belong to the union of two sets, it cannot belong to one of the sets, right?

Comment: The third line of your proof should be $\implies x\notin A \lor x\notin B$, right? A point fails to be in an intersection of sets if and only if it fails to be in at least one of the sets.

Comment: @MPW yeah that's what is in Wikipedia's formal proof.

Answer (score 4):

> \begin{align} \implies x  \notin (A \cap B )
> \end{align}
> \begin{align} \implies x  \in A  \lor x \in B
> \end{align}

$$A=\{1,2\},~~B=\{2,3\},~~x=5$$

So $x\notin A\cap B$ but you can't say $x\in A $ or $x\in B$

Answer (score 2):

The denial of the conjunction is the disjunction of the denials. That is why the proposed "proof" does not work. Here is a formal way to proceed.

Let $A = \{x\in U : p(x)\}$ and $B = \{x\in U : q(x)\}$. According to the properties of the logical operators involved as well as the definition of intersection and union of sets, the proposed identity holds true:
\begin{align*}
(A\cap B)^{c} & = \{x\in U : \neg(p(x)\wedge q(x))\}\\\\
& = \{x\in U : \neg p(x)\vee\neg q(x)\}\\\\
& = \{x\in U : \neg p(x)\}\cup\{x\in U : \neg q(x)\}\\\\
& = A^{c}\cup B^{c}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!